# Possible exception thrown by CFile in MFC Library

Tags: c++

Currently, I am investigating some code that uses the `CFile` class from the MFC Library to open a text file.

I found two kinds of error handling in the code: This are just sample since it is confidential to post the code.. Just think that the body of the try statement contains only member functions of CFile class.

#### 1

```
try {
     if(file.Open(strPath,Cfile::modeRead|CFile::shareDenyNone)){
     file.Read(strKey, dataLength);
     file.Close();

   }
}
catch (CFileException& e) {
}
```

#### 2

```
try {
    // same code above
}
catch (CFileException *e) {
}
```

1. What is the difference between the two kinds of exception handling?
2. What are the possible errors that can be thrown by member functions of the `CFile` class?
3. Is no. 1 way possible for catching exceptions thrown by a member function of the `CFile` class?

Comment: Where did you see this "line of code"?

Comment: Hi All! they are having discussion with their egos..I dont know f that is still part of the answer... hehehe just understand

Comment: "Most People do not listen with the intend to understand; They listen to intent to reply"... I think this is the explanation to their misunderstanding below.. But anyway I need some suggestions from  anyone...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can throw exception objects in two ways, by value:

```
CException ex;
throw ex; // CException
```

or by pointer:

```
CException *ex = new CException();
throw ex; // CException *
```

When catching the exception, you catch the corresponding type of what has been thrown, that is, a pointer, or a value. To avoid a copy, we usually catch-by-value using a reference:

```
catch(CException &e) // when throwing CException
```

---

MFC throws exceptions by pointer; see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e5twxsh.aspx

```
try {
   AfxThrowUserException();
}
catch( CException* e ) {
   e->Delete();
}
```

Don't forget do delete the exception afterwards, or you get a small memory leak each time an exception is thrown.

Comment: i.e. RTFM as I said. And you did not answer the whole question, which includes asking about the difference between the two "exception handling styles" in C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, but you did. I don't see the point in duplicating your answer's content.

Comment: so no.1 way   is not possible for catching a pointer type of exception since  MFC throws exception by pointer?? is that what you mean??

Comment: @Mr.kbok: My answer has been overrun by trolls. Feel free to reproduce that part of the answer.